# Does Linux support TRIM for SSDs on LVM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, ssd, trim

I am getting a SSD and need to know, does Linux support TRIM if I set up LVM on top of the SSD? I'm finding conflicting information. I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.10 with kernel 2.6.35-28.

Answer (score 8):

Trim support was added for LVM in the 2.6.37 kernel ([source](https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2011-January/msg00035.html)). However, combining LVM and RAID does not currently support TRIM.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/a/228714/115189), TRIM works correctly through ext4+LVM+mdraid as of Linux 2.6.38. (thanks to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37571/how-to-configure-a-filesystemlvm-for-effective-usage-of-ssd))

Answer (score 0):

Until the Kernel Version 2.6.33 the TRIM command in inserted to the kernel.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM) are some information.