# Does Windows 7 support TRIM for Spanned Dynamic Disks?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, lvm, trim, dynamic-disk

**Windows 7** supports **TRIM** for an individual **SSD**, but does it work with **two SSDs** merged together as a **Spanned Dynamic Disk**?

"Dynamic Disk" is **Microsoft**'s proprietary version of **LVM**.
The **equivalent feature** for **Linux** was **[added in kernel 2.6.37](https://superuser.com/a/267595/180616)**.

Comment: Related (deals with a spanned volume using an HDD and SSD): [Will Trim still work if creating a spanned volume of two disks](http://superuser.com/questions/257385/will-trim-still-work-if-creating-a-spanned-volume-of-two-disks-not-as-raid). Also somewhat related: [Is TRIM supported on RAID 0 configurations for SSD drives in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/139804/is-trim-supported-on-raid-0-configurations-for-ssd-drives-in-windows-7). As for spanning, most on [this thread](http://www.overclock.net/t/1165983/spanning-2-ssds-into-single-volume-any-downsides) say Trim is *not* supported.

Answer (score -1):

NO.

As far as i can see, that is.
Trimming on dynamic discs is not possible.
noticed trimming was "greyed" out in my favorite defragger after changing my startup-drive from basic to dynamic.

btw, changing the offset 1c2 in sector zero of the startup PARTITION (not physical harddrive) to hex "07", didn't help, win7 blue screened in every boot attempt.
"Chkdsk c:" revealed a "raw" file system, which cannot be automatically resolved.
Changing 1c2 in sector zero of the first partition back to hex "42" resultet in succesfull booting of the machine.

(hex 07 Basic disc, hex 42 Dynamic disc, which worked just fine using WinXP sp3)